# How to pass a function that takes an iterator as a function parameter in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, higher-order-functions

I want to pass a function that takes an arbitrary iterator over some type (e.g. `String` in the example below) into another function, but I don't know how to specify the type of such a function.

Here is a minimal (non-working) example of what I'm trying to achieve. The compiler cannot infer the type of `I`.

```
fn process<I>(lines: I)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String>, // or IntoIterator
{
    for line in lines {
        println!("{}", line.to_uppercase());
    }
}

fn run<F, I>(processor: F)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String>,
    F: Fn(I),
{
    let v = vec![
        String::from("aaa"),
        String::from("BBB"),
        String::from("cCcC"),
    ];
    processor(v.iter());
}

fn main() {
    run(process);
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass a generic function. You can pass a specific instantiation of a generic function. Do you need `run()` to call `processor()` with an arbitrary iterator, or only with a specific iterator (like `std::slice::Iter` in this example)?

Comment: A generic parameter gives the _caller_ the freedom to choose the type. But the caller cannot choose `I` here because `F` must take, specifically, something of the same type as `v.iter()`. I do not think Rust has a way to say something along the lines of `Fn<I: Iterator<...>>(I)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` isn't passing any `Iterator<Item = String>` it's currently passing a very specific `std::slice::Iter<'_, String>` so you can't have a generic `I: Iterator` on it. Anyways `slice::Iter<'_, String>` implements `Iterator<Item = &String>` not `Iterator<Item = String>` (note the additional/absent `&`) so `process` doesn't even accept it.

You probably meant to write this:

```rust
fn process<I>(lines: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = String>,
{
    for line in lines {
        println!("{}", line.to_uppercase());
    }
}

fn run<F>(processor: F)
where
    F: Fn(std::vec::IntoIter<String>),
{
    let v = vec![
        String::from("aaa"),
        String::from("BBB"),
        String::from("cCcC"),
    ];
    processor(v.into_iter());
}

fn main() {
    run(process);
}
```

or this alternative `run`:

```rust
fn run<F>(processor: F)
where
    F: Fn(Vec<String>),
{
    let v = vec![
        String::from("aaa"),
        String::from("BBB"),
        String::from("cCcC"),
    ];
    processor(v);
}
```